# Conditions on cssClass in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic4

I'm taking over a mobile project at my new work, which has a badge system, on click, it displays a modal with the badge.
I would like to display a small "V" image on it if the user owns the badge, which is easily done with some ngIf, but in this case the previous developer is using the modalController which takes cssClass as an attribute for styling, is there a way to make conditional statements on this or will I have to recreate a modal on my own?
Here's the modal code:

```
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: ModalBadgePage,
            cssClass: 'modal-badge',
            mode: 'md',
            componentProps: {
                // id: currentId,
                title: badgeTitle,
                description: badgeDescription,
                image: badgeImage,
                hunts: badgeHunts
            }
        });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

you can add your condition like below mentioned .. where `1==1` is the `condition check` and if this is true it will add `modal-badge` class else it will add `modal-badge2` class to this modal

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: ModalBadgePage,
            cssClass: (1==1) ? 'modal-badge' : 'modal-badge2',
            mode: 'md',
            componentProps: {
                // id: currentId,
                title: badgeTitle,
                description: badgeDescription,
                image: badgeImage,
                hunts: badgeHunts
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi mate please vote up and accept the answer in case you found it usefull and correct answer